# How to Integration of nagios/icinga and github tickets and their content into zendesk and sync open/closed status?

Tags: nagios, zendesk, icinga2, icinga, icingaweb2

Before zendesk, ive used zammad, which has a nice integration of gihub / nagios / icinga tickets etc. and f.e. closes them if services are back online.
Is it possible to get the same functionality in zendesk ?

Is it possible to not just forward tickets to zendesk by email, but also have a back channel to nagios (or preferrable icinga) to

- acknowledge warnings
- close warnings
- close tickets in zendesk that were opened by a warning email, if the service is online again ?

Comment: Hello @Andreas, this website is more about programming stuff and your "problem" is not. Try use serverfault.com instead.

Comment: Im aware that this is a site for (mostly friendly) programmers. Well, i found other zendesk and nagios related topics here and was creating the question from the zendesk tag page. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zendesk) . This IS about progrmming "stuff", since f.e. emails are processed by regex based tagging and there are also REST connectors, so i assume someone used them for a similar problem

Comment: also, there are hundreds of zendesk related questions on stackoverflow and not even a zendesk tag on serverfault, so i guess this is the more likely place to find an answer

Answer (score 0):

Zendesk provides a developer friendly [API](https://developer.zendesk.com/rest_api/docs/support/tickets.html) that can be used to manage ticket resources.  In addition, there is form of webhooks available in Zendesk called [targets](https://support.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/203662136?page=1#comment_211802467).  These can be used to push data to an external source based off of events in Zendesk.  You could also poll the API via the [Incremental Tickets API](https://developer.zendesk.com/rest_api/docs/support/incremental_export#incremental-ticket-export) endpoint.